# C custom data type

Tags: c

I believe this question has been asked many many times, but I do not think there is a concrete answer.
If there is, I cannot find it, please direct me if possible.

Anyways, does C support any way to abstract bytes/words/dwords into a certain representation?

floating point and double precision floating point appear to be core features, but they are not actually
new data types, but re-representation of existing dword/qword.

so, I wonder, is it at all possible to do something like this:
let mydatatype be an unsignedbyte which auto-negates itself at compilation.

eg.

```
mydatatype a = 0xff;
```

would be represented in binary form as 0x00;

I ask because C++ tries to remedy this with overloading =, and classes, but it does a little
more abstraction than I would want, because say, i'm allowed to do this:

```
memcpy(&my_int, &my_float, 4);
```

then I would be allowed to to bitwise manipulations to play around with int, and 
put it back by

```
memcpy(&my_float, &my_int, 4);
```

whereas, I am not convinced that if say, float was defined as a class, I could do this low level
manipulation, instead it completely abstracts away all ways to deal with it other than the class methods.

I am curious because, If this is not a feature of C language, why not, it appears to fit perfectly with
the rationale of including floats and doubles, but we cannot create complex numbers, even though they
would be about as simple to add to c language as floats and doubles.

This has been bothering me for quite some time, mostly because as soon as I want to create a data type, I start migrating towards the realm of void pointers, structs, and hetrogenous data types, which seems
to be un-necessary.

eg:
void *my_data_type = my_data_type_new(0xff);
which would "negate" 0xff to 0, and store it in memory pointed to by my_data_type.

this seems un-necessary, because all I want is
negchar my_data_type = 0xff;

which a compiler could manage to recognize.

and then I could

```
memcpy(&my_char, &negchar, 1);
```

and my_char would be 0.

the above does not hold in C++ classes...

floats, doubles are abstract in the sense that they behave in their own way, while maintaining ABI, but they are not really much different than say, complex numbers, as a complex number can also be represented using a particular ABI.

I mean, I don't think I can even declare a long long long (can I?) without resorting to creating typedefs...

To make this actually a question, I will narrow down the answers to:
Is this feature available in C? if so, how can I do this?
If not, has such a feature ever been considered, if not is this just because floats, doubles are special due to historical need for real number representation that made this abstract feature a core feature?

I mean, I understand that languages like Fortran supported real numbers by default, but i'd think that C would be able to take this feature out of "core feature" and allow a way for a programmer to create abstract ABI types without need to resort to pointers to memory blocks that need to be freed, and allow stronger type checking while at it.

In particular, it is very strange how the only abstract static data structures with full abstraction, are float and double, to my knowledge. Whereas all other practices play with dynamic memory, or allow abuse of notations(using a char, but only modifying it with functions).

Conclusion:
C++11 appears to support this, adding new data types to C would be very confusing, floats and doubles are needed due to natural demand of real representations in programming, and while the feature could be implemented through abstract data types, it made sense at the time to make them part of the language core.

Thanks!
~Dmitry

Comment: Indenting a line with 4 spaces causes it to be formatted as code. Use the [edit] link to improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C core language provides no means to re-interpret literals in any way other than what the standard provides for.

C++11, on the other hand, introduces user-defined literals, by which you could meaningfully write

```
negbyte operator "" _nb(unsigned long long);

negbyte val = 0xff_nb;
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to know, the nb isn't exactly what I wanted, but it does what I did. thanks.